# Postman main source code repository?

Tags: postman

I'm looking for the Postman main source code repository. Is this publicly available?

All I seem to be finding on https://github.com/postmanlabs is helper apps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the list of pull request and the comments there, it seems like indeed Postman's core application is closed source:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/pulls?q=is%3Aclosed

Answer (score 0):

There is postman main repository: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/tree/master

Comment: Looking at the list of pull request and the comments there, it seems like indeed Postman's core application is closed source: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/pulls?q=is%3Aclosed